# how to deploy a report type from sandbox to production

Tags: deployment, custom-report-type

It does not seem to be possible to deploy a report type using the deployment wizard in salesforce. How can I deploy a report type from my sandbox to my production org? I need detailed instructions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to find them under **Custom Report Types** in the **Add to Change Set** menu. Once you've added them to your Change Set you can deploy them as you would any other component.